# Taking multiple slices of numpy 1d array from given indices, copying result into 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, vectorization

New to Python. Given in the code snippet below is a numpy 1d array called *randomWalk*. Given indices (which can be interpreted as start dates and end dates, both of which may vary from item to item), I want to do take multiple slices from that 1d array *randomWalk* and arrange the results in a 2d array of given shape.

I am trying to vectorize this. Was able to select the slices I wanted from the 1d array using `np.r_`, but failed to store these in the format I require for the output (a 2d array with rows representing items and columns representing time from `min(startDates)` to `max(endDates)`.

Below is the (ugly) code that works.

```
import numpy as np

numItems = 20
numPeriods = 12

# Data
randomWalk = np.random.normal(loc = 0.0, scale = 0.05, size = (numPeriods,))
startDates = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 5, size = numItems)
endDates = np.random.randint(low = 5, high = numPeriods + 1, size = numItems)
stochasticItems = np.random.choice([False, True], size=(numItems,), p = [0.9, 0.1])

# Result needs to be in this shape (code snippet is designed to capture that only
# a relatively small fraction of resultMatrix's elements will differ from unity) 
resultMatrix = np.ones((numItems, numPeriods))

# Desired result (obtained via brute force)
for i in range(numItems):
    if stochasticItems[i]:
        resultMatrix[
            i, startDates[i]:endDates[i]] = np.cumprod(randomWalk[startDates[i]:endDates[i]] + 1.0)
```

Comment: Since the slices can vary in length, you can't apply them to all rows at once.  In some cases slices like this can be converted to `advanced indexing` arrays, but often that requires just as much iteration.  In addition you have the `stochasticItems` test, and the `cumprod`.  I don't see a way of "vectorizing" this.

Comment: What is the main aim of the question? Vectorizing or improvement in performance?

Comment: @Ali_Sh The aim is improvement in performance. This routine is called during each iteration of a Monte Carlo simulation. Code profiling suggests this routine takes up a sizable fraction of total runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [@mozway 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73613515/17980931), convert irregular slices into regular mask array:

```
>>> # build all arrays with np.random.seed(0)
>>> x = np.arange(numPeriods)
>>> mask = (startDates[:, None] <= x) & (endDates[:, None] > x)
>>> result = np.where(mask & stochasticItems[:, None], np.where(mask, randomWalk + 1, 1).cumprod(-1), 1)
>>> np.allclose(result, resultMatrix)
True
>>> result
array([[1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.0489369 , 1.16646468, 1.2753867 ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        , 1.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the vectorization is the goal, so it is done by [Pig answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73616900/13394817), If it is not matter (as it is mentioned by the OP in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73610419/taking-multiple-slices-of-numpy-1d-array-from-given-indices-copying-result-into#comment130001178_73610419) --> *The aim is improvement in performance*), so I suggest using numba library to accelerate the code. We can write `np.cumprod` equivalent numba code and accelerate it using numba no-python jit:

```
@nb.njit
def nb_cumprod(arr):
    y = np.empty_like(arr)
    y[0] = arr[0]
    for i in range(1, arr.shape[0]):
        y[i] = arr[i] * y[i-1]
    return y


@nb.njit
def nb_(numItems, numPeriods, stochasticItems, startDates, endDates, randomWalk):
    resultMatrix = np.ones((numItems, numPeriods))

    for i in range(numItems):
        if stochasticItems[i]:
            resultMatrix[i, startDates[i]:endDates[i]] = nb_cumprod(randomWalk[startDates[i]:endDates[i]] + 1.0)
    return resultMatrix
```

This code improved the code `~10 times` faster than the OP in my some benchmarks.