# Set all values between 2 ranges in numpy array to certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 1d arrays of type int and a start and a stop value that look like this:

```
y_start = #some number
y_end = #some number
x_start = #some array of ints
x_end = #some array of ints
```

What I want is to simulate the following behavior without loops:

```
for i, y in enumerate(range(y_start, y_end)):
    arr[x_start[i]:x_end[i], y] = c
```

Example:

```
y_start = 2
y_end = 5
x_start = np.array([2, 1, 3])
x_end = np.array([4, 3, 6])
c = 1
```

**Input**

```
arr = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**Output:**

```
arr = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: what does `arr` look like? Please provide an explicit complete example (input + output)

Comment: This is for triangle rasterization so arr is pretty big but ill put smaller example.

Comment: Yes, please use a minimal example (also provide the start/end values and the output)

Comment: Alright I did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use indexing and a crafted boolean arrays converted to integer:

```
v = np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None]
                                                  # conversion to int is implicit
arr[:, y_start:y_end] = ((v>=x_start) & (v<x_end))#.astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```